# cross domain reading remote url using Jquery/Ajax/Json

Tags: json, jquery

I have an HTML page from which i want to read a remote webpage which is at http://xtremeinspection.com/new2you4kids/app/android/get_product_size.php?productID=113

The webpage returns a value depending on the Query string parameter passed that is the productID

My question is since its cross domain reading data which is the best method to use Jquery/Ajaz/Json or mix of all these ?

I have searched it on Google but i cant find example of **reading and displaying the data in a DIV .**

**I am using this code but it doesnt display anything**

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('http://xtremeinspection.com/new2you4kids/app/android/get_product_size.php?productID=113', function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i, tweet){
                        $('#tweets').append('<li>' + tweet.text + '</li>');
                        alert(tweet.text);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

 <ul id="tweets"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic example like this should help you get started:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "gulmarg",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 5 ) return false;
    });
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkkkt/)